# Make background image scale to size of content in front

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a div with an image and a div inside of it with content. I need to make the background image be the size of whatever the content is, so grow/shrink accordingly.

Right now, it only shows the full size of the image which results in a lot of space being left where there is no content.

Here is my current styling, it is required I used flexbox.

```css
.section {
    height: 100%;

    .section_image {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 100%;

        img {
            object-fit: cover
        }
    }

    .content {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div className="section>
    <div className="section_image">
        <img src={Image} alt="" />
    </div>
    <div className="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Body Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you want to use background-image and background-size CSS properties?

Comment: @AntonNevsgodov I would love to lol unfortunately I'm not permitted to as using image tags is better for SEO

Comment: Lol wtf. Maybe you can just add that image in your html but apply `display: none` to it in css and use background-image idk.

Comment: @AntonNevsgodov I thought of that too haha but I think it be best to just do it how they want, using flex box and position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section {
    height: 100%;
 }
.section_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden
}
.section_image {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}
img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: fit-content
}
.content__elements {
    display: flex;
    z-index: 2;
    color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="section_wrapper">
         <div class="section_image">
            <img src="https://www.gardendesign.com/pictures/images/675x529Max/site_3/cosmos-pink-flower-pixabay_11886.jpg" alt="" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content__elements">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>Body Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```